# Blender 2.77: How to I create a path for an object to follow with latitude, longitude, & altitude (in feet) coordinates in csv format?

Tags: coordinates, blender

I have a csv of lat., long., and altitude data from flight 24.
I want to make a path for an object to follow in blender, but the path has to be generated from the above data.
I also want to import a 3D-model of the place where the aircraft flew over.

The problem is I need to use blender 2.77 because the another add-on I want to use only supports v. 2.77. Add-ons like blender-osm and blender-gis only supports the most up to date version of blender.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have x y z coordinates for each point of a path then you can easily able to create a `path` curve using `bpy`. Here is an example:

```
import bpy

def create_curve(coords_list):
    crv = bpy.data.curves.new('crv', 'CURVE')
    crv.dimensions = '3D'
    spline = crv.splines.new(type='NURBS')
    spline.points.add(len(coords_list) - 1) 
    for p, new_co in zip(spline.points, coords_list):
        p.co = (new_co + [1.0])
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new('object_name', crv)
    bpy.data.scenes[0].collection.objects.link(obj)

cords_list = [
[0,0,0],
[1, 0, 1],
[2, 0, -1],
[0, 0, 2]
]

create_curve(cords_list)
```

Output:
[image: blender_path_curve_example]